# Xodo app alternatives

Tags: windows, pdf

I hope you can help me

I am a Windows user. I've used Ubuntu several times and I want to switch but there are a few things that prevent me from switching to linux like the lack of some of my favorites app. And one of those apps is XODO PDF Reader & Annotator. I love this app. I want to know if there is an alternative for linux. If you haven't tried this app, do it. There is a web version but the desktop version for Windows is much better. Please I need to find something like this for linux. I really like Ubuntu and want to switch but I need to find all the alternatives for my Windows apps.

Comment: Which features of "XODO PDF Reader" do you want? We at AskUbuntu are generally unfamiliar with Windows software.

Comment: For example, I study languages and I use textbooks. But I use those scanned documents, so I have to take annotations on the pdf. One of the features is that even if I don't have a touch screen or a stylus I can take annotations with my mouse. I can draw lines, create a text box and write whatever I want over the scanned document. You can try the web app if you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Okular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okular) app. Just type following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install okular
```

It has all the features of note making.